# Docker saving data

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I run a container and, say, install vim. I exit out of the container. I would then like to re-run the container and have still have vim installed.

Is there a way to do this, because every time I restart a container vim is never there.

Comment: @EvanCarslake The consensus on meta stack overflow was that docker questions are in an overlap area.  [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276579/should-docker-questions-go-on-stackoverflow-or-serverfault-or-superuser)    The present question is simply a beginner docker question that could easily be from a fellow software developer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do this, because every time I restart a container vim is never there

They are still there. when you run

```
docker ps -a
```

You should see all of them, some of them are not in running status, but in exited status.

There are two ways to re-use the same container. For example,

#### List all containers with `docker ps -a`

```
$ docker ps -a |grep 9c8e962f21e7
9c8e962f21e7        centos:6    "bash"     6 days ago    Exited (137) 2 seconds ago   boring_stallman
```

#### run with `docker exec`

```
docker start 9c8e962f21e7
docker exec -ti 9c8e962f21e7 bash
```

You should be fine to login and run vim if you installed it before.

#### run with `docker attach`, if the container start with bash

```
docker attach 9c8e962f21e7
```

Comment: it would also be worth mentioning what the `docker commit` command does as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/30960800/107049

Answer (score 0):

You should build this container from a Dockerfile. So something like

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get install vim
CMD some command
```

That way the containers you run from this image have vim.

**EDIT 1**

Additionally, you can commit your container to an image, that way the current state of that container is saved to an image that you can spawn additional containers with the same state.

Comment: isn't there a way to just have the data and/or changes I made inside the docker persist to the next time I use it?

Comment: See my edit above for best way to use a running container for this.

Answer (score 0):

In Docker there are *images* and *containers* .  When ever you `docker run` something, the something is an original copy and that is the *image* and is *unmodified* no matter what happens in the container.  The copy running in the *container* acquires a new layer in the container's filesystem that isolates any changes to that one container.

You can use `docker commit <containerid> <imagename>` to save changes from the temporary container to a new permanent image.

However, for reproduction and documentation purposes it is better to do builds from a Dockerfile.

Here are the docs for docker commit.

```
docker commit --help

Usage: docker commit [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]

Create a new image from a container's changes

  -a, --author=""     Author (e.g., "John Hannibal Smith <hannibal@a-team.com>")
  --help=false        Print usage
  -m, --message=""    Commit message
  -p, --pause=true    Pause container during commit
```