# Docker save file

Tags: python, docker, boot2docker

I have a docker image running right now, and access it by boot2docker. I use Python on this, with all the libraries installed.
My problem is that I can't save any file or images on Docker. I just execute a little script that save an image in jpg format, but nothing is saved. I give all the rights to the repository, and no one error appears.
I use cv2.imwrite for saving image. cv2.imread is working.

Thank for the answers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Docker saving data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960738/docker-saving-data)

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to add a volume to you local disk. Then such image will be saved in the directory you specified and survive container starts/stops etc. Here are the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/).

Comment: I will try this answer, I will tell you after if it works or not. Thanks for the quick answer !

Comment: I created a data volume with this :
docker run -d -P --name coucou2 -v /coucou:/app myname/myrepo python exe.py
but nothing appears in my Windows repository, and if I execute with the current image, nothing too ...

Comment: @DockerUser, I didn't know You use windows. Please see the following tutorial: https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#folder-sharing, it might be helpful. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: I tried this morning, so the command lines are running well, but impossible to access to the http://192.168.59.103/data, even with FileZilla or simply in the browser bar or on Windows Explorer. I restarted the VM in VirtualBox, but same error "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". I tried to use the port 2022 too, but same

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you need to server the volume's content an HTTP server to do that.

Comment: In fact, I want to execute a python file that will save files into the server. So I understood that it store files created in the server, but when I want to access to the server I can't because of this error. Maybe I didn't understand well a part

Comment: Where's the script executed? On the host or on image? Unfortunately I'm not windows user so I can't reproduce it.